# Use double quotes by default when importing in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, dart

Every time I auto-import stuff using Android Studio, the import is single quoted by default, which is against the linting rules I use. How can I change it that it defaults to importing with double quotes.

For example, instead of:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

I would like that auto-import generate this line by default:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
```